# Unable to deploy from solution from WSPBuilder because preflight requirements fail

Tags: deployment, wspbuilder

I have a box where SP2010 is just installed and seems to be working. When I'm trying to deploy a solution using WSPBuilder, I get these errors:

SharePoint is not installed on MYSPBOX
Microsoft SharePoint Services Administration is not running on MYSPBOX
Microsoft SharePoint Services Timer is not running on MYSPBOX
Preflight requirements failed.

SharePoint is indeed installed, and I can access it just fine through the browser. Both "SharePoint Services Administration" and "SharePoint Services Timer" are running.

What could be missing and where should I check?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the solution to the machine you are developing on, or is it a remote machine?

Comment: It's to the machine I'm developing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing the correct version of WSPBuilder. I was using WSPBuilder Extensions 1.0.6 but realized now that I need WSPBuilder Extensions 2010 BETA 1.4 to make it work with SP2010.